# AVFoundation Recording Not Enough Disk Space Error Code 11807

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I am writing a small video that is only 100kb in size. My phone has about 20mb left on disk, but when I try create a recording using AVFoundation and AVCaptureMovieFileOutput, I get the error:

```
2014-06-15 10:40:19.511 wave[551:690b] ERROR: 
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain
Code=-11807 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo=0x157cde20 
{NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=There
is not enough available space to continue the file writing. 
Make room by deleting existing videos or photos
```

I am setting the

```
self.movieFileOutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = //space available in bytes
```

thinking it would override this default behavior, but it's not. Any idea how to continue allow for recording given the disk space parameters?

Update - here is the code I'm using to get free space:

```
-(uint64_t)getFreeDiskspace {
    uint64_t totalSpace = 0;
    uint64_t totalFreeSpace = 0;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];

    if (dictionary) {
        NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];
        NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
        totalSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
        totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
        NSLog(@"Memory Capacity of %llu MiB with %llu MiB Free memory available.", ((totalSpace/1024ll)/1024ll), ((totalFreeSpace/1024ll)/1024ll));
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error Obtaining System Memory Info: Domain = %@", error);
    }

    return totalFreeSpace;
}
```

Comment: Some of the device's "disk space" is reserved so it has RAM, is it not?

Comment: @nhgrif - see updated code. I think I know what you're asking... but if I try other apps, I am able to create video. i.e. I can record a video in Vine, so there must be a way to override this default behavior, right?

Comment: Which directory are you using to save data?

Comment: NSTemporaryDirectory()

Comment: @nhgrif Definitely not. iOS does not use disk (flash) for swapping, or any other "RAM"-like purpose.